# FormsAuthentication Behaving odd

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Is this a security issue or by design?

string UID = "randomusername" // does not exists in aspnet_Users table
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UID, false);

Authenticates users, redirects to login page.

Profile Page is set to chech User.Identity.IsAuthenticated etc...

when they update the profile, it ads the user to the aspnet_users table automatically, which is not what I want.

Comment: Is there any logic in your profile page that creates an account if one doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage doesn't perform any valid user check; it just redirects the user as they are a valid user.  It assumes that you have done the validation check first before you called this.

HTH.

Comment: Yes but why would it be adding a user to the aspnet_users table?

Comment: So basically you can call FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("bogusUser", true); and it will add a user to your users table?

Comment: No, it will add a cookie.  Like you said though, it probably is a feature built into the profile to create the user, not from RedirectFromLoginPage.  That would make sense because the Profile table requires an entry in aspnet_Users to work.

Comment: What Brain is saying is correct. If you don't create a user using asp.net membership, but want to use asp.net built-in Roles or Profile provider, a user will be automatically created in aspnet_Users table. The profiles table has FK relationship to aspnet_Users table via UserId.

Comment: I just thouhgt it was odd is all. Obvously I am validating before hand.

Comment: If you are validating, how are they not in the users table then??

Comment: Brian, just my test was not validating is all. I put the validation code back in :)